# Why does SQL Server prevent me from creating these foreign keys?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

My (abridged) schema has (or rather, would need) the following tables and relationships:

```
Clients (ID INT PRIMARY KEY)
Files (
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Client INT REFERENCES Clients(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE)
Interfaces (
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Client INT REFERENCES Clients(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE)
Files_Interfaces (
    "File" INT REFERENCES Files(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    Interface INT REFERENCES Interfaces(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

So as you can see from this schema, a Client can have multiple files and multiple interfaces. There is a many-to-many relationship between interfaces and files (hence the junction table `Files_Interfaces`), and the only hierarchical relationships are to Client (there is a one-to-many relationship from `Clients` to `Files` and `Interfaces`).

I'd need these constraints between `Files_Interfaces` and `Files` and `Interfaces` so that, if I delete a file or an interface, all the related associations are destroyed.

The problem is, SQL Server 2005 won't let me have this schema. When I try to create Files_Interfaces with such constraints, I get the following error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   'FK__Files_Int__Inter__3D2915A8' on
>   table 'Files_Interfaces' may cause
>   cycles or multiple cascade paths.
>   Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON
>   UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other
>   FOREIGN KEY constraints.

What gives? Is it because if I delete a client, then both files and interfaces are deleted and then `Files_Interfaces` records have two good reasons to disappear? If so, why is it a bad thing?

Can I somehow prevent this error?

Comment: no, I'm completely off track, ignore my comment ...

Comment: in theory, your schema is viable and you could actually create it in, say, `PostgreSQL`. It's `Microsoft`'s implementation that does not allow you to do that.

Comment: Apologies for my answer, I misread your script above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While there is nothing wrong with multiple cascade paths (and even cycles) in theory, the implementation of them may be hard.

As it is now, `SQL Server` requires that the cascade graph should be a tree rather than a directed acyclic (or even worse, cyclic) graph:

> The series of cascading referential actions triggered by a single `DELETE` or `UPDATE` must form a tree that contains no circular references. No table can appear more than one time in the list of all cascading referential actions that result from the `DELETE` or `UPDATE`. Also, the tree of cascading referential actions must not have more than one path to any specified table. Any branch of the tree is ended when it encounters a table for which `NO ACTION` has been specified or is the default.

Due to implementation limitations, `SQL Server` does not optimize cascade deletes as a single set-based operation, rather, it splits the tree into a series of individual joins. In case of `A -> B -> C`, `DELETE A` is not a `DELETE A JOIN B JOIN C` but rather a `DELETE A JOIN B OUTPUT B_temp` followed by `DELETE B_temp JOIN C`.

In case of multiple cascade paths, it would lead to multiple `B_temp`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanantion.